# How to completely uninstall munin on Ubuntu or RaspberryPi?

Tags: uninstall, munin

I would like to uninstall `munin`, including the configuration files. How do I do that?

Comment: Please review https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. At least show that you have made an effort to try and solve this yourself.

Comment: as the how-to-ask page explains you need to explain what you've done/tried/researched to the question so users of this site know you've made an effort. It is a matter of respect. Often it also helps avoid getting answers/comments that are irrelevant or that propose things you've tried. The question you posted shows none of that. Try to read your own question as if it was posted by someone else before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following on Ubuntu and RaspberryPi:

1. Uninstall the package:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt-get purge --autoremove munin
   ```
2. Remove the configuration files:

   ```bsh
   sudo rm -rf /etc/munin/
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/munin/
   sudo rm -rf /var/cache/munin/
   ```